# how to access multidimensional arrays in php?

Tags: arrays, multidimensional-array

Can someone help me on how to access items in this array? i am using codeigniter  framework, and i have come to a point that i have to insert values into a table from an array of this type....

```
 Array(    
  [0] => Array
    (
        [0] => Learn PHP programming
        [1] => 2
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [0] => Practice PHP
        [1] => 2
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [0] => Work
        [1] => 8
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [0] => Do exercise
        [1] => 1
    ));
```

Answer (score 1):

Use foreach for accessing such type of arrays. In your case, this is multidimensional.

```
foreach($yourArray as $value){
    $data['table_column_1'] = $value[0];
    $data['table_column_2'] = $value[1]; 
   $this->db->insert('your_table_name',$data);
}
```

In your case, **table_column_1** is the column in your table where you wanna store the first index of your array.

Answer (score 0):

As you have mentioned you are using Codeigniter, you can use `$builder->insertBatch()` of query builder in the Codeigniter database library.

You just need to reformat your current array. You can iterate through the array to do so.

```
$data = [];
foreach($currentArray as $value){

    $data[] = [
        'title' => $value[0],
        'id' => $value[1]
    ];
}
```

Your array would look as follows

```
Array(    
    [0] => Array
    (
        ['title'] => Learn PHP programming
        ['id'] => 2
    )

    [1] => Array
    (
        ['title'] => Practice PHP
        ['id'] => 2
    )
    .
    .
```

And then use

```
$builder->insertBatch($data);
```